# How to call a child component's exposed method when mobx changes?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I would like to have a simple Timer (countdown) component that exposes methods like pause, reset and start that its parent component can calls when appropriate.

The parent component uses MobX for state management, and I would like to call the above methods without re-rendering the child based on global MobX store changes.

I have an example on Codesandbox, that shows the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/q7n1248onq?fontsize=14

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if both a parent and a child need access to a method, have the parent pass it to the child. There are plenty of exceptions to this, but it may get you where you need to be.